# javamail class not found while trying to run on RHEL

Tags: java, linux, classpath, jakarta-mail

I was asked to configure and use javamail on a RHEL 7 server.
I untar'ed a javamail directory they had here which contains the following files:

- activation.jar
- cacerts
- config.properties
- InstallCert.class
- InstallCert$SavingTrustManager.class
- mail.jar
- SimpleSSLMail.class

Also, I have created a `/etc/profile.d/java.sh` where I have the following:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jre1.6.0_45
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:$PATH
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/javamail/activation.jar:/usr/share/mail.jar:.
```

cacerts is a keystore which holds gmail's cert to sendmail. When I try to send mail using the following:

`java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="cacerts" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword="somepassword" SimpleSSLMail "SomeHeader" "Testing..." "some@mail.com"`

It fails with message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   SimpleSSLMail Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   SimpleSSLMail
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) Could not find the main class: SimpleSSLMail.  Program will exit

I have reviewed many posts saying the problem is java not finding mail and activation jars, but I can't handle correctly the CLASSPATH to work with those files. I also tried using `-cp` flag like this: `java -cp mail.jar -cp activation.jar -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="cacerts" .....`
It was useless, I get the same error.
What am I missing or how do I get it to work? 
I have java jre only; do I need to compile it using javac? 
My goal is to make it work in order to create an alias where the user can type only `sendmail "Message" "mail.com"` or similar

## UPDATE

I was having a typo in classpath where instead of using `/usr/share/javamail/mail.jar` I was using `/usr/share/mail.jar`.
Now, when creating the alias it works fine in javamail directory but if I try to run it outside the directoy, java complains that it doesn't find config.properties. I believe it is searching for it as `./config_properties`.
I don't have the source code, so, is there a way to override the config.properties location with the command line?

Comment: Are executing the `java` call in `/usr/share/javamail` folder?

Comment: yeah, or with full path to SimpleSSLMail

Comment: Looks like instead of `.` you need to add `/usr/share` (or whatever directory `SimpleSSLMain.class` exists).

Comment: Yeah, that was it, I had a typo in the path of mail.jar. However, now trying to create the alias and using it outside the directory holding simplesslmail class, java is unable to find config.properties.